# How to make setState working in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, fetch-api

i am using fetch API to fetch from an API.
After fetching the result i want  to setState to the reult which is not working
this is the function that fetches the results

```
export const random = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;


export const getPokemons = async function () {
  const pokemon = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    pokemon.push(fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${random(1, 800)}`));
  }
  return Promise.all(pokemon)
    .then((data) => {
      const parsedData = [];
      data.forEach(async (d) => {
        const resJson = await d.json()
        parsedData.push(resJson);
      });
       return parsedData
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

the  code where it is imported

```
  const [stats,setStats] = useState([])
  useEffect(()=>{
      generateTrio()  
        },[])
        
    async function generateTrio() {
        const gTrio = await getPokemons();
        setStats(gTrio)
        console.log(stats,gTrio)
        }
```

stats here is an empty array , while gTrio is required results i want to be in setStats

Comment: Don't log `stats` after calling `setStats()`, just use `stats` to render your elements and it will work like you expect.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts  i'm sure that it's an emty array even after the `setState` is called.
[link to codesanbbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-roentgen-chre5?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is twofold:

- You're logging `stats` in the same closure as you call `setStats()`. See [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) for an explanation of why doing this will log the previous state.
- You're passing an `async` function to the callback of `forEach()` which pushes the data into the array after the outer promise has resolved with the initially empty array. See [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) for potential pitfalls of this anti-pattern.

Your `getPokemons()` was returning an empty array from your asynchronous function, and then asynchronously populating it *after* it's used to render your `Main` component.

Even if you were logging `stats` in the correct closure, Chrome's developer console output would be confusing since it would show you that the array was populated even though it was empty at the time it was logged. See [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays) for more information about this developer console behavior.

One correct way to write `getPokemons()` would be:

```js
export const getPokemons = () => (
  Promise.all(
    Array.from({ length: 5 }, async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${random(1, 800)}`);
      return response.json();
    })
  )
);
```

And a correct way to write your `Main` component would be:

```js
const Wrapper = styled.div``;

const Main = () => {
  const [stats, setStats] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const setPokemons = async () => {
      setStats(await getPokemons());
    };

    setPokemons();  
  }, []);

  // console.log(stats);

  const names = stats.map(item => ( 
    <p key={item.id}>{item.name}</p> 
  ));

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {names}
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set function of usestate does not set state immediately and synchronous. I think it like async method. Bu it is not only real reason.
You can check this message at similar topic. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58877875/12239744